# Twilio browser call incoming connection status

Tags: javascript, webrtc, twilio

In a browser to browser call, when Bob doesn't answer Alice's call, Alice receives no answer and disconnect from Bob, but Bob never knows Alice disconnected.

How does Bob know that Alice disconnected?

Alice:

```
var connection;

Twilio.Device.setup(token);
Twilio.Device.connect(onConnect);
Twilio.Device.disconnect(onDisconnect);

function onConnect(conn) {
  connection = conn;
  console.log("onConnect: " + connection.status()); //onConnect: open
};

function onDisconnect() {
  connection.disconnect();
  console.log("onDisconnect: " + connection.status()); //onDisconnect: closed
}

$('.close').one("click", function() {
  Twilio.Device.disconnectAll();
});

$(document).ready(function () {
  Twilio.Device.connect({
    agent: 'bob'
  });
});
```

Bob:

```
  var connection;

  Twilio.Device.setup(token);
  Twilio.Device.incoming(onIncoming);
  Twilio.Device.disconnect(onDisconnect);

  function onIncoming(conn) {
    connection = conn;
    console.log("onIncoming: " + connection.status()); //onIncoming: pending
  }

  //never arrives here when caller disconnect
  function onDisconnect() {
    console.log("onDisconnect: " + connection.status());
  }
```

Comment: Do you have a call to Device.setup() in your code?

Comment: yes there is with a token. dont have problem with it just when caller hangup other browser not notified at all.i m curious if twilio client has a function something like connection statuses change get notified would solve all the problem that i face.

Comment: there is no generic "status changed", but when the `disconnect` function is not on the Device, its on the Connection object, so you need to connect the connection object you get in the `incoming` function to the function you want to run when the connection disconnects

Comment: can you give an example code of it? just for clarify

Comment: hmm..reconsidering my last comment.  Give me a bit to write some code.  So to be clear, what you are seeing is if Alice calls Bob, and Bob doesn't answer, Alice does not call the  disconnect handler?

Comment: i updated my question.also in alice side works everything perfectly but bob not knows that alice disconnection if no answer.